# autoheight for different html pages

Tags: html, css

I have always used this way of working as for multiple page html website, I have used a class for a basic page CSS and then id for single page height fix.
Well I want know that am I doing this right or I have to use Autoheight for container divs. Which one is more efficient?

eg. for about page I use

```
<div id="aboutContainer" class="mainContainer"></div>
```

Then do this

```
#aboutContainer
{
    height:1200px;
}
```

or should I choose autoheight for the class `mainContainer`?

Comment: Well if you're talking efficiency, the only efficiency to discuss is the work you put in coding the page. The effect that the extra code will have on the user experience is so minute that it is truly negligible. It might be the difference of 5ms to download the extra content (as it makes the CSS file larger), but this is so small that you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: you can use  min-height:1200px;  other according to your requirment  other will  adjusted acordingly if more then this

Comment: CSS is quite efficient in it of itself. If it looks the way it should on all browsers and you are happy with it, your method of accomplishing it is not really *wrong*. Of course there are conventions as with any language, but a result you are pleased with is ultimately the only gauge.